# Deduplicate style-loader and css-loader runtime code

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-loader

Currently, when you try importing styles with css-loader and style-loader, loader runtime defined in [style-loader/addStyles.js](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader/blob/master/addStyles.js) and [css-loader/lib/css-base.js](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/blob/master/lib/css-base.js) is imported every time for every chunk that contains reference to required styles, which creates unecessary duplicated code.

Is there any official way to move that code to some "runtime entry point" and then handle it with `CommonsChunkPlugin`, just like with [standard Webpack chunk manifest approach](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/chunkhash)?

My current (not thoroughly tested) approach is to include those two files in some runtime entry point and then use `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` to replace every future instance of those two requires with those defined in runtime entry point:

```js
module.exports = {
    entries: {
        runtime: [
            'style-loader/addStyles',
            'css-loader/lib/css-base',
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            names: ['runtime'],
            minChunks: Infinity
        }),
        new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(new RegExp('style-loader/addStyles'), require.resolve('style-loader/addStyles')),
        new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(new RegExp('css-loader/lib/css-base'), require.resolve('css-loader/lib/css-base'))
    ]
};
```

Does this make sense?